# Phpldapadmin error = This base cannot be created with PLA

Tags: openldap, centos7, phpldapadmin

I am currently trying to install and configure an OpenLDAP server on a CentOS 7 VM.

I have been following [this video](https://youtu.be/Kyqr58CQ_wc) and I am stuck at the moment.

The part I am stuck in is when I get the following message when I login into `phpldapadmin`:

> (This base cannot be created with PLA. dc=my-domain,dc=com).

On video: 18:34

I tried to import the following details for the ldif file but I get a syntax error after.

what to enter

```
 dn: dc=my-domain,dc=com
 dc: my-domain
 objectClass: top
 objectClass: domain
```

I am new to OpenLDAP so I am not too familiar with it, so please excuse my noob questions. I left everything as default before I started making the changes.